# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.configuration.IllegalConfigurationException:

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-flink, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy my flink application `helm install appname .`
App is getting deployed but pod is getting crashed
values.yml

```
flinkConfig:
      # Task Manager Config
      taskmanager.memory.process.size: 1200m
      taskmanager.memory.flink.size: 670m
      taskmanager.memory.task.heap.size: 300m
      taskmanager.memory.task.off-heap.size: 50m
      taskmanager.memory.managed.size: 0m
      taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: 160m
      taskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.min: 20m
      taskmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.max: 400m
      taskmanager.debug.memory.log: false
      env.java.opts.taskmanager: "-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xloggc:/code/target/mps-fhr-ai-svc-tm.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/srv/"
    
      # Job Manager Config
      jobmanager.memory.process.size: 630m
      jobmanager.memory.flink.size: 500m
      jobmanager.memory.heap.size: 300m
      jobmanager.memory.off-heap.size: 200m
      jobmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size: 130m
      jobmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.min: 20m
      jobmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.max: 400m
      env.java.opts.jobmanager: "-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xloggc:/code/target/mps-fhr-ai-svc-jm.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/srv/"
```

[image]

I have updated with different values but still the same exception. Any help will be helpful.

Comment: I think your answer is here , but I really like to know why you set a value for overhead memory. https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/deployment/memory/mem_setup/#capped-fractionated-components